# Can output file directory be specified via command-line?

Tags: command-line-arguments, nsis, output

I have an `.nsi` file which I call via command-line to output the installer, like this:

```
makensis fullPathToNsiScript
```

This creates the installer in the folder where my `nsi` script is. I need to output it to a specific folder, say desktop. **Is it possible to do that via command line?**

I know the correct way is to specify it in the script itself, like

```
OutFile "outputFileFullPath"
```

But is it possible to do via command-line assuming I'm only providing the base-name of the output file in the `nsi` script? Something like:

In script,

```
OutFile "outputFilename"
```

and then in command-line,

```
makensis fullPathToNsiScript "outputFileFullPath"
```

? The above obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
makensis "/XOutFile $%temp%\test.exe" setup.nsi
```

(Running `Makensis /?` will show a similar example, /X can be used to execute any NSIS command)

The makensis.nsi example uses another tactic, specifying the outfile on the commandline is optional (`/DOutFile=foo.exe makensis.nsi`) and the script uses a !ifdef with a hard-coded fallback...

Comment: the first one worked for me, but I had to remove `OutFile` command from original script.